# Best practice in Asp-MVC for filling lookup values in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, viewmodel

I have an small web mvc dummy app with one create form (using viewmodel). The view model has bounded values and non-bounded (e.g. the lookups). But first you can see my example code below:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// I'm the model from persistence layer.
/// </summary>
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
    }
    public Product(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// I am optimized for view.
/// You can give me a name and select a product.
/// </summary>
public class DummyViewModel
{
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HiddenInput()]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductLookup { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class DummyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var dummyViewModel = new DummyViewModel()
        {
            Name = "New Dummy",
        };
        UpdateLookupsOnViewModel(dummyViewModel);

        return View(dummyViewModel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I'm the pingback action-method if client has filled the create form.
    /// If given viewmodel is invalid or if saving failes 
    /// the given viewmodel will be returned.
    /// If that happens then it will loose all the lookups.
    /// So they must be updated again in that two cases.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(DummyViewModel vm)
    {
        if (vm == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // 1. Given viewmodel is invalid, so update the lookups.
            UpdateLookupsOnViewModel(vm);
            return View(vm);
        }

        try
        {
            // Save into repo.
            throw new Exception("Dummy exception, which simulates an error while saving.");

            return Redirect("stackoverflow.com");
        }
        catch
        {
            // 2. Saving failed, so update the lookups.
            UpdateLookupsOnViewModel(vm);
            return View(vm);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateLookupsOnViewModel(DummyViewModel vm)
    {
        if (vm is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vm));
        }

        vm.ProductLookup = GetProductsFromRepository()
            .Select(o => new SelectListItem(o.Name, o.Id.ToString()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I simulate the access to database.
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsFromRepository()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Product(1, "My Product"),
            new Product(2, "BB Super"),
            new Product(3, "Jooooe"),
            new Product(4, "Igel"),
        };
    }
}
```

Below you can see the ASP-HTML-View

```html
@using Experiment.Web.ViewModels

@model DummyViewModel

<form asp-action="Create">
    <input asp-for="Id"/>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <div class="div-input-aussen"><input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="ProductLookup" class="control-label"></label>
        <div><select asp-for="ProductId" asp-items="@Model.ProductLookup" class="form-control"></select></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="ProductLookup" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Speichern"/>
</form>
```

My problem you can read in the comments, but in short: The non-bounded values in viewmodel (**ProductLookup**).

If the client use HTTP-Get to request the create form then a new **DummyViewModel** is created. If he filled all required values he use HTTP-POST and send the DummyViewModel to the Controller Action.
If the controller action detects that the given viewmodel is **invalid** or the saving process **failed** he sends the given viewmodel back to the client.
If that happens all the non-bounded values are lost, so they must be updated again on the viewmodel.

My lookup values are stored in database (in the real app). So it could be a performance issue.

Now I want to know how other people are handling this situation. Do you use caching? What is when I forget to call **UpdateLookupsOnViewModel** before return it?
Have you some coding styles which helps or any pattern?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: If you have a tool like Kendo, you can have it make it's own AJAX calls to populate the dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are best practices as such just different approaches.

Personally I think your `UpdateLookupsOnViewModel` method is the way to go; but if I/O performance in your repository is a concern you could use `TempData` or `Session` to persist the values in memory. The other way would be to store the values in a hidden field, maybe as JSON or a delimited string, then post that back and reconstruct your list.

Unfortunately, HTTP is stateless, so these are just different ways of mimicking state in your app.

Answer (score 0):

As we are talking about web, I call a method to fill in the lookups twice: One for `GET` (the usual) and one for "exceptions" (`POST` - invalid submitted data, etc.). That, however, degrades performance since I am hitting the DB all the time.

The solution I found was to [cache the lookup in memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.0). But you will need to think about what kind of lookup data you have (how often it changes, how big it is, how long should you keep in cache, etc.) in order to define your caching strategy.

My general rule for caching is to keep all lookups separated by using different cache keys ("cache_prod", "cache_prod_type") so you can rebuild only the one that was changed when it happens.

You could probably do something like this:

```
private void UpdateLookupsOnViewModel(DummyViewModel vm)
{
    if (vm is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vm));
    }

    vm.ProductLookup = GetProductFromCache("cache_product");
}
```

The method `GetProductFromCache` could look roughly like this:

```
private Product GetProductFromCache(string cacheKey)
{
    IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    Product product;
    if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out product))
    {
        product = GetProductsFromRepository()
                    .Select(o => new SelectListItem(o.Name, o.Id.ToString()));
    }

    return product;
}
```